# unsigned char array to key in the stl::map or other container

Tags: c++, stl, null

I try to make a map like

```
 map<unsigned char[16], string> testMap;
```

And `unsigned char[16]` looks not suitable type for key map.

but in my key have NULL, so I can't use string for key..

example key:

```
 01 bc 03 00 50 03 00 00 89 00 10 00 ff ff ff ff
```

this kind of key also can use `map.find()` ?

Or Is there any other good container for me?

THANKS :)

Comment: Errr.... `std::string` can perfectly well have null bytes inside.

Comment: You could always define your "key value" as your own type that plays well with map. It will probably save you time in the long run and improve the self-documentation of the code. std::string may hold null characters, but I would say this would be something that has the potential to cause confusion in the future.

Comment: Consider using `std::array` when you have a known compile-time size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `std::string` constructor that builds the string from a char array (not a C-String). This takes two parameters - a pointer to the array and a length:

`std::string   x("pq\0rs");`   `// Two characters because input assumed to be C-String`
`std::string   x("pq\0rs",5);` `// 5 Characters as the input is now a char array with 5 characters.`

This allows for embedded null characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use STL vector instead of unsigned char array

NOTE:

If you are using c++11 and have fixed length of characters,use std::array. 
If you don't have fixed length or are not using C++11 or above go for std::vector

Comment: In this case (where the length seems to be known compile-time) `std::array` would be a better fit.

Comment: @You but the std::array came since c++ 11 i guess,i don't know what version of c++ the guy is using so i gave the answer which is not C++ 11 or above dependent

Comment: @You: Look again at the question: I don't think the OP *wants* a fixed-size array. It's an XZ-problem, the fixed-sized array was only the best thing the OP could think of throwing into the question as his best guess.

Comment: In that case, why not give both? Certainly C++11 should be the default these days.

Comment: @KerrekSB absolutely,even that was one of the reasons i gave this as answer

Comment: @You look into the comment made by kerrek

Comment: That's certainly a valid point, but I don't think the question is clear enough on that issue. Mentioning both alternatives wouldn't have hurt, was what I was getting at.

Comment: If a c++11 stl container can be suggested, I would rather suggest `std::array` because the length is fixed.